# Find data on a subset of data between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL, and have a table A which has a list of study ids, and a list of user ids tied to the studies. So it's a one to many for study to users.

I have a table B, which lists study ids, and a list of user ids who have completed training for these studies.

Not everyone in table B is in table A.
Some courses in Table B have a portion of users that have completed training, and some have courses where no one has done any training.

For the courses that have partial completion, how do I find out which users are missing training/have no training records?

---

**Table A (Studies):** StudyId, UserId

**Table B (Training):** StudyId, UserId, TrainingDate

---

**Sample Data:**

**Table A:**

Study Id: 1   :::::   UserId: 1
Study Id: 1   :::::   UserId: 2
Study Id: 1   :::::   UserId: 3
Study Id: 2   :::::   UserId: 1
Study Id: 2   :::::   UserId: 2
Study Id: 3   :::::   UserId: 2
Study Id: 3   :::::   UserId: 3

**Table B:**

Study Id: 1   :::::   UserId: 1 ::::: TrainingDate: 01-01-2016 
Study Id: 1   :::::   UserId: 3 ::::: TrainingDate: 02-01-2015 
Study Id: 3   :::::   UserId: 3 ::::: TrainingDate: 02-04-2016

---

**Expected Output:**

From the data above, Study 2 is the only study that there are no certifications at all for (which I've figured out how to get). What I need is the studies which are partially completed, and to figure out who's missing for those studies.
So my expected data set would be: 
Study Id: 1   :::::   UserId: 2
Study Id: 3   :::::   UserId: 2

---

As I stated above, I've figured out how to get the users/studies with no training dates, and for that I used the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA WHERE StudyId IN(SELECT A.StudyId 
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON B.StudyId  = A.StudyId
WHERE B.StudyId IS NULL)
ORDER BY StudyId
```

But I need to get those partially completed studies. And I know it's staring me right in the face, but can't seem to think it through correctly.

Comment: what have you tried, please post your existing query its results and your expected results

Comment: can you provide small samples of your tables?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The query selects records that do not exist in both tables. As result, we can determine what training has no assigned date, and what training have truants.

```
select
  a.StudyId,
  a.UserId,
  (
      select top 1 1 from TableB
      where StudyId = a.StudyId and TrainingDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ) as 'Training was assigned' -- You may find this useful for additional analysis
from TableA as a
left outer join TableB as b
  on a.StudyId = b.StudyId and a.UserId = b.UserId
where b.StudyId is null;
```

Comment: Please add some context around your answer to help the OP. It helps everyone.

Comment: @RBT I know better SQL, than English :)